# parameter passed in constructor initialisation in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, parameter-passing

```
class GameController;

class Snake : public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    enum Direction {
        NoMove,
        MoveLeft,
        MoveRight,
        MoveUp,
        MoveDown
    };

    Snake(GameController & controller); // <<<<<<<<<
};


Snake::Snake(GameController &controller) 
: head(0, 0)
, growing(7)
, speed(3)
, moveDirection(NoMove)
, controller(controller)
{ }
```

What did this statement do? I mean what does that parameter do when the constructor is initialised?

Comment: What it does depend on how you implements it.

Comment: It doesn't compile, since Snake does not have a member or base called `controller` - or indeed `head`, `growing` etc. Without a complete example, how can anyone tell?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Snake(GameController & controller);
> ```
>
> What did this statement do?

It's just the declaration of a `Snake` constructor taking a `GameController` reference as parameter.

> I mean what does that parameter do when the constructor is initialised?

The parameter itself does nothing when the *constructor is initialised*. The constructor's body code might call any operations on it, or stores it to a class member variable (which is actually the case, regarding your additional information).

But that can't be really told here definitely, since we don't see the definition of the `Snake` constructor.

Comment: gamecontroller is a class itself.so to implement it first we need to create a instance of it, isnt it?. is it creating the instance? if so how ?the snake constructor has this inside
Snake::Snake(GameController &controller) :
    head(0, 0),
    growing(7),
    speed(3),
    moveDirection(NoMove),
    controller(controller)
{
}

Comment: @Ccr _"we need to create a instance of it, isnt it?"_ Yes you first need to create an instance of `GameController` and pass it, when constructing an instance of snake. [Add additional info, about the constructor body to your question please.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28394849/edit)

Answer (score 0):

What it does depends on your constructor code.

The parameter comes into effect when the constructor is called.

When the constructor is called, it passes the value by reference, other than that nothing else can be said unless you provide your code.

Comment: there are lots of cpp and header file 
this is the content of snake.cpp
#include <QPainter>

#include "constants.h"
#include "gamecontroller.h"
#include "snake.h"

static const qreal SNAKE_SIZE = 10;

Snake::Snake(GameController &controller) :
    head(0, 0),
    growing(7),
    speed(3),
    moveDirection(NoMove),
    controller(controller)
{
}

Comment: The parameter passes the address of whichever object you send to it and then the object controller is send to controller(controller)!!!!!!!. We can't give a more detailed explanation until you give us more of your code or at least intend your code so that we can understand what each function is doing( that is if you are the one who really made this code )